# xml to json using Node.js with node having partcular name as array type

Tags: arrays, json, xml, node.js, npm

I try to parse a xml string to json in such a way that a node having particular name should always be an array type.
I am using

> npm node module xml2js

for

> conversion of xml to json.

I need an array type conversion for a node having a particular name.
How do I make an **array type conversion** for a node having a particular name?

```
"children": { "id": "211c838e-3e2d-4919-ab09-dd7f8a901b97", "parentId": "a4968d08-aaee-45c6-bc75-849830226248"}

"children": { "id": "15b3e6b9-b546-4bf6-9787-322ecce469c1", "parentId": "c5c14c51-be3f-4d8b-866c-243367d785fd", "offset": { "x": "-107", "y": "109" }, "foldChildren": "false", "branchColor": "#000000", "children": "" }
```

The objects above are the part of my json string which has children as object.
 I need that all objects with the name `children` should be of the type array.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: should i give conversion code or sample xml string?

Comment: Can you post the JSON object?

Comment: "children": {
                "id": "211c838e-3e2d-4919-ab09-dd7f8a901b97",
                "parentId": "a4968d08-aaee-45c6-bc75-849830226248"} this is the part of my json string which has children as object. I want that all others having name children should be array type

Comment: "children": {
                  "id": "15b3e6b9-b546-4bf6-9787-322ecce469c1",
                  "parentId": "c5c14c51-be3f-4d8b-866c-243367d785fd",
                  "offset": {
                    "x": "-107",
                    "y": "109"
                  },
                  "foldChildren": "false",
                  "branchColor": "#000000",
                  "children": ""
                }

Comment: In above json object there are two objects with name children. In whole json files its many more. what i need is to have all object having name children should be array